# Can I save and load login profiles for apps in appium?

Tags: python, android, android-studio, android-emulator, appium

If we set the capability `noReset` to True, we can stay logged in to apps we've logged into before when testing.

Suppose I have different accounts on my app (Account A, Account B). Can I log into each of them once and save the profiles somewhere so I can load them later and instantly be logged into those accounts? I see there's a method driver.get_cookie is that what it's for? Then how can I load cookies.

You would, for example, be able to do this in firefox by saving userprofile and loading them again. So is there a way to do this in appium?